# SQL Total of a column but 2 rows multiply each value by a set value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello i am trying to get the total of 2 rows by multiplying 1 value by 200 and the other by 50.

I got a table like

```
=====================
ClubName | Type | Fee
=====================
Club1    |Adult | 1000
Club1    |Child | 500
```

I am trying to multiply the 1000 by 200 and the 500 by 50 and than add them and that is the total that i am trying to get.

I got the one for adult but how do i than go for child and than plus them?

```
SELECT Type, SUM(Fee * 200) AS MembershipFee
FROM fees
WHERE Clubname='hillcrest' AND Type='adult'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then this should work:

```
SELECT Type, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Adult' THEN Fee*200 
         WHEN Type = 'Child' THEN Fee*50 END) AS MembershipFee
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE Clubname='hillcrest'
 Group BY Type
```

You can do the following if you just want to get the sum.

```
SELECT Clubname, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Adult' THEN Fee*200 
         WHEN Type = 'Child' THEN Fee*50 END) AS MembershipFee
FROM yourTable
WHERE Clubname='hillcrest'
Group BY Clubname
```

Comment: Yes that multiplied the values. Do you know how i can add the 2 results together now?

Comment: select clubname and group by it instead of type.  this approach is called conditional aggregration as you only sum the multiplied values of adult and child (all other values would be null).  If there is a type 'pet' it would not be included in the results.  So replace type in the select and group by with clubname.

Comment: xQbert Thank you very much

Comment: @T.Ryan  ideally you would store the 200, 50 in a table along with the type instead of hardcoding these values in the SQL.  You would then join the new table to yourtable on type and then the 200 and 50 would be a value in the new table.  Thus if the value changes, you change data not code.  If you have a table which already lists the types, one could simply add a column to it.  Assuming the type is a unique value.  Rule of thumb is to store data/config in a table; don't store data in code.